# Batch rename via command line?

Tags: image, rename, batch-processing

I have a Media Temple (dv) server which I am setting Magento up on.

I have uploaded a few thousand images to the /media/import directory that the client has provided me with. The problem is, some images are .jpg and others are .JPG.

Is there a way of batch renaming them on the server? I really don't want to have to do it locally and the re-upload them all.

I would ideally make them all lowercase so that they are uniform with the other image naming schemes used by Magento.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bash suggestion:

```
   for file in *.JPG; do newfile=`echo $file|sed 's/.JPG$/.jpg/'` ; mv -i "$file" "$newfile" ; done
```

It loops over all the files with a .JPG extension, and for each of them it uses sed to construct the new filename by turning a terminal .JPG into a terminal .jpg, and performs the mv.  The `-i` is just in case you have a fred.JPG *and* a fred.jpg already.  Don't forget to distinguish between single quotes and backticks, both of which are used, and **aren't** interchangeable.

Comment: Or use the preferred `$()`. Also, variables that contain filenames should always be quoted in case there are spaces in the names.

Comment: Dennis is absolutely right, I should have thought of that, and have modified the above accordingly.  On the other hand, filenames with spaces are an aberration and should be avoided anyway!  (opinion! opinion!)

Comment: Should I just run this from within the directory using Terminal?

Comment: @dannymcc: Yes. MadHatter: Photographs and music are two of the file types that one should expect to spaces in their names.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the utility called `rename` installed (it's a Perl script) you can do:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```